# How I make my laptop running elementary OS display normally, rather than only a few shades of colours?

Tags: display, laptop, horus, eos7

When booting into elementary OS 7 Horus (with disk encryption) on my laptop normally, the disk unlock screen is displayed. After entering my decryption key, it loads into tty7, where it briefly flashes a grey screen with a cursor, before the screen appears to go black (the backlight is still on).

Then this phenomenon occurs: only the (sharpest?) colours on the screen are shown, and everything else appears black.

Photos (in order) of the login screen, desktop, and desktop with app launcher open are attached below.
[image: The login screen; desktop; and desktop with app launcher]

This issue does not occur in recovery mode, however it appears to resume after the laptop is suspended and then reopened.

For reference, this is a picture of the laptop in recovery mode, specifically in the third scenario, with the app launcher open on the desktop:
[image: App launcher and desktop displayed correctly]

The following snippet is the output of `/var/log/syslog`. The screen started displaying incorrectly around 01:35:44.

```
May 20 01:35:40 oskars-laptop systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
May 20 01:35:42 oskars-laptop dbus-daemon[1130]: [session uid=115 pid=1130] Activating via systemd: service name='ca.desrt.dconf' unit='dconf.service' requested by ':1.13' (uid=115 pid=1188 comm="io.elementary.wingpanel -g " label="unconfined")
May 20 01:35:42 oskars-laptop systemd[1107]: Starting User preferences database...
May 20 01:35:42 oskars-laptop dbus-daemon[1130]: [session uid=115 pid=1130] Successfully activated service 'ca.desrt.dconf'
May 20 01:35:42 oskars-laptop systemd[1107]: Started User preferences database.
May 20 01:35:43 oskars-laptop bluetoothd[740]: src/adv_monitor.c:btd_adv_monitor_power_down() Unexpected NULL btd_adv_monitor_manager object upon power down
May 20 01:35:57 oskars-laptop systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of UID 1000.
```

Additional information:

- CPU: Intel Pentium N3710
- Memory: 4GB
- Kernel version: Linux 5.15.0-58-generic

Comment: Is there any message in `/var/log/syslog` around the time of resuming that reports an issue with the video subsystem? 

Comment: Is there a way to check that log between restarts? It’s kinda difficult to read the log when I have no output.

Comment: The records have timestamps, so scrolling back should be feasible after a reboot 

Comment: Edited the question with a snippet of the log. Appears to have something to do with bluetoothd. Any idea?

Comment: After disabling the bluetooth service, issue still occurs. Seems to be a problem with the other logs. I'm suspicious of the user preferences database.

Comment: any ideas? I haven't figured out what's wrong after some more looking-into